# Windows Failover Cluster not online during creation of SQL Always On Availability Group

Tags: powershell, azure, failovercluster

I've been following this tutorial to create an Azure SQL AlwaysOn Availability Group using Powershell:

[Tutorial: AlwaysOn Availability Groups in Windows Azure (PowerShell)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870963.aspx)

When I get to the command that invokes the CreateAzureFailoverCluster powershell script, I check the state of the failover cluster. In Failover Cluster Manager, it is shown as "the cluster network name is not online"

When I look at the Cluster Events, I see this:

```
Cluster network name resource 'Cluster Name' cannot be brought online. Ensure that the network adapters for dependent IP address resources have access to at least one DNS server. Alternatively, enable NetBIOS for dependent IP addresses.
```

Each of the 3 servers in the cluster has access to the DC via ping. All of the preceding setup steps execute correctly. The servers are all on the 10.10.2.x/24 IP range except the DC, which is on 10.10.0.0/16 (with IP of 10.10.0.4)

All of the settings have been validated by prior execution of the tutorial on a different Azure subscription to create a failover cluster that works fine.

Cluster validation reveals this warning:

```
The "Cluster Group" does not contain an Cluster IP Address resource. This is a required resource for the group. It may be difficult to manage the cluster with this resource missing
```

(sic)

How do I add a Cluster IP Address resource?

Comment: DC is Windows Server 2008, both SQL servers are 2012

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the configuration or the steps taken.

It took the cluster 3 hours to come online.

Attempting to bring the cluster online manually, failed for at least 20 mins after creating the cluster.

The Windows Event logs on all 4 servers showed nothing to say when the cluster moved into the online state.

It seems the correct solution was to work on something else until the cluster started under its retry policy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup a fixed IP address in the cluster, using the cluster manager? there's a bug, DHCP will assign the cluster the IP address of one of the sql server isntances. I just assigned a high enough number (x.x.x.171, I think), and the problem went away.